# Change last line of text to red based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, colors, fonts

I want to run a macro that changes the line of text in column E to red if the text starts with a date that is in this month. I have put a formula in cell E1 which is month/year e.g. 08/22. I have tried to run this formula and I get no errors but the text is not changing to red.

```
Sub Text_To_Red()
'
' Text_To_Red Macro
'
Dim D As String
Dim P As Integer
Dim L As Integer

For E = 9 To 5000

D = Range("E1").Value
P = InStr(Cells(E, 11).Value, D)
L = Len(Cells(E, 11).Value)

If InStr(1, Worksheets("Live Project Notes").Cells(E, 11), D) <> 0 Then
    Worksheets("Live Project Notes").Cells(E, 11).Characters(Start:=P - 2, Length:=L).Font.ColorIndex = 3
End If

Next
MsgBox ("Font Colour Change Complete")

Cells(1, 1).Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you share the formula in `E1` and some sample data from column `K`? Is the `Live Project Notes` worksheet in the workbook containing this code? You haven't qualified the ranges that you use when assigning values to the `D`, `P` and `L` variables. Are they in the same worksheet and workbook and what are their name(s)? You haven't declared the `E` variable: why don't you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: Is the value in `E1` an actual date formatted as _mm/yy_?  If so then `E1` will hold a numeric value such as _44806_ for _2nd September_.  You'll then try and match this with the text value _09/22_ that the string starts with.